# Converting Raster into Vector in QGIS

Tags: qgis, r, vectorization

I am in process of converting one raster file ( JBA Flood score) into Vector file But due to raster size ( Possibly) process seems endless i.e. even after 9 hours process still continue. Is there any additional plugin, tool to perform the same. I have used Polygonize tool. I am ok with writing R code as well if anyone has any leads.

Comment: Converting raster to polygon is very slow. Have you tried exporting a smaller part of the raster and converting this, maybe your computer runs out of memory or something? Or downsample the raster to a lower resolution

Comment: Hi for smaller region it is doable but when it comes to large area like country it is taking much time. Unfortunately can't clip them in smaller part. Have to do with one large single file

Comment: Why? Merge or Dissolve them afterwards into a big polygon layer. You can create a model which does the clipping and converting, you dont have to do it manually

Comment: You could convert the raster to contour lines and the lines to polygons.

Comment: If you don't need the vector file to represent each cell with its exact value, but rather a classified vector file (e.g. polygons representing low, medium and high values) you could reclassify the raster first, using r.reclass. Could you give an example of your input data and what you want as an output?

Comment: What is the resolution and size of your raster? Is it continuous numeric values (like height) which is difficult to vectorise or categorical?

Comment: @BERA yes i can do that let me try that but as i have to do this for multiple country and multiple files. By any chance do you have any available model for this

Comment: @C.-F.Vintar Actually i need with actual value of each cell. Re classification may not work. For information its a JBA Flood score data.

Comment: @Spacedman Yes its a continues data consisting flood score for each pixel.

Comment: @Erik I have tried your suggestion it is partially done i am just performing some of QAs for that. Mena while any other suggestion would be really helpful

Comment: Could you convert the raster into a point layer? That is usually much faster than polygonize.

Comment: Continuous data are *not* suitable for vectorising. How do you form polygons if each pixel is a different value to all its neighbours? If you convert from continuous to discrete by maybe classifying each value as low, medium, or high, then you get something that might be vectorisable into polygon areas.